# Single click on button for voice recording

Tags: android, button, voice-recording

I am working on an Android application in which I am using voice recording functionality, for this I am making the button tapping for the recording like if user hold the button for more than 3 seconds then it will allow for the recording.

For this I am using Touch listener, but the problem is that if user just click the button without keeping it hold then the recording or function is called. My code is given below:

```
mBtnSendAudio.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            boolean shouldRecord = true;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(!canChat) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Turned Off Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mLastDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    shouldRecord = true;
                    startRecording();
                    mLLAudioRecordingHover.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    rectAudioButton = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
                    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    mRecordHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    mRecordHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    if (shouldRecord) {
                        mLLAudioRecordingHover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mLastDuration = System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastDown;
                        mRecordHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                        mLLAudioRecordingHover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        stopRecording(true, mLastDuration);
                    }
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

                    // finger move outside of button's bounds
                    if (!rectAudioButton.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop()+ (int) event.getY()) && shouldRecord) {
                        mRecordHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                        shouldRecord = false;
                        stopRecording(shouldRecord, 0);
                        mLLAudioRecordingHover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Once try as follows

```
mBtnSendAudio.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mRecordHandler.postDelayed(run, 3500/* OR the amount of time you want */);
            break;

        default:
            mRecordHandler.removeCallbacks(run);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

and here is Runnable to change status of recording

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
     shouldRecord = true;

}
```

};

**UPDATE :**

Then you have to use **GestureDetector** as follows

```
private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

then in onTouch(-,-) of OnTouchListener

```
 if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1)) {
                // single tap
              //write your code for single click
                return true;
     }
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply. With holding a button it is working but if i just click on the button it won't work. Please help me out in this. Thanks

Comment: what you want to do if user click on the button?

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices right here: first you can forget about the 3 seconds and use View.OnLongClickListener which is a standard listener used by most of the developers to detect a press and hold event or you can set a timer inside `if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {}` condition here is the code for a 3 second timer:

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        //your caode
                    }
                }.start();
```

use your desired functionality inside `onFinish()` method.